# How do I get an unlock code for my locked account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My account is locked and I tried to recover my account but Supercell asks various questions and I tried answering all but some answers are not accurate so I can't recover my locked account. How can I get my unlock code without the help of Supercell support agents?

Answer (score 4):

Did they send you an unlock code to the email linked to your Supercell ID?

If not, you unfortunately have to get it from support one way or another.

There's no magic master code to input that works for all accounts. Don't believe these unlock code generator websites, they're just scams that won't give you the code.

Comment: Not only will they give you a probably bogus code, they will now have a lot of the information I guess is needed to get the real one. So they could steal your account and try to resell it somewhere.